# Calculate Win Rates In Python Using Groupby and Lambda Functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, countif

I'm trying to create a new df from `race_dbs` that's grouped by `'horse_id'` showing the number of times `'place' = 1` as well as the total number of times that `'horse_id'` occurs.

Some background on the dataset if it's helpful;

`race_dbs` contains horse race data. There are 12 horses in a race, for each is shown their odds, fire, place, time, and gate number.

What I'm trying to achieve from this code is the calculation of win rates for each horse.

- A win is denoted by `'place' = 1`
- Total race count will be calculated by how many times a particular 'horse_id' occurs in the db.

`race_dbs`

| race_id | horse_id | odds | fire | place | horse_time | gate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| V14qANzi | 398807 | NaN | 0 | 1 | 72.0191 | 7 |
| xeieZak | 191424 | NaN | 0 | 8 | 131.3010 | 10 |
| xeieZak | 139335 | NaN | 0 | 1 | 131.3713 | 9 |
| xeieZak | 137195 | NaN | 0 | 11 | 131.6310 | 11 |
| xeieZak | 398807 | NaN | 0 | 12 | 131.7886 | 2 |
| ... | ... | .. | .. | ... | ... | .. |

From this simple table the output would look like, but please bear in mind my dataset is very large, containing 12882353 rows in total.

`desired output`

| horse_id | wins | races | win rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 398807 | 1 | 2 | 50% |
| 191424 | 0 | 1 | 0% |
| 139335 | 1 | 1 | 100% |
| 137195 | 0 | 1 | 0% |
| ... | .. | .. | ... |

It should be noted that I'm a complete coding beginner so forgive me if this is an easy solve.

I have tried to use the groupby and lambda pandas functions but I am struggling to combine both functions, and believe there will be a much simpler way.

```
import pandas as pd

race_db = pd.read_csv('horse_race_data_db.csv')
race_db_2 = pd.read_csv('2_horse_race_data.csv')

frames = [race_db, race_db_2]
race_dbs = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

race_dbs_horse_wins = race_dbs.groupby('horse_id')['place'].apply(lambda x: x[x == 1].count())
race_dbs_horse_sums = race_dbs.groupby('horse_id').aggregate({"horse_id":['sum']})
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For count `True`s values create helper boolean column and aggregate `sum`, for `win rate` aggregate `mean` and for count use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) in named aggregations by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
out = (race_dbs.assign(no1 = race_dbs['place'].eq(1))
               .groupby('horse_id', sort=False, as_index=False)
               .agg(**{'wins':('no1','sum'),
                    'races':('horse_id','size'),
                    'win rate':('no1','mean')}))
print (out)
   horse_id  wins  races  win rate
0    398807     1      2       0.5
1    191424     0      1       0.0
2    139335     1      1       1.0
3    137195     0      1       0.0
```

Comment: Wow that's awesome (and answered in 2 minutes!). 

Is it strictly necessary to insert new lines for .groupby and .agg? Or is this personal preference to help with clarity?

Comment: @EdLee - It is for readable code and clarity.

Comment: Why does 'mean' work? It doesn't make sense that 'mean' would work to calculate win rate for all possible values of wins and races.

Comment: @EdLee Because working with True values processing like `1`, False like `0`, so if use mean get win rate, beacuse it is mean of all 1 from all values of column.

Comment: ok got it! 

How about this adaptation? 

There is another column (G) that contains mother_horse_id. You want to calculate how many times a horse_id from column (B) occurs in mother_horse_id from column (G). 

Would you need to .assign another value at the start to make mother_id = horse_id? ... Just trying to wrap my head around adapting the code to do all of this in one go.

Comment: @EdLee I think the best is create new question.

Comment: Hey, is it possible instead of no1 to include all values between (and including) 1-6. 
So, values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6?

Answer (score 1):

**can you try this way:**

**Example code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

new_technologies= {
    'Courses':["Python","Java","Python","Ruby","Ruby"],
    'Fees' :[22000,25000,23000,24000,26000],
    'Duration':['30days','50days','30days',  '30days', '30days']
          }

print('new_technologies:',new_technologies)
df = pd.DataFrame(new_technologies)
print('df:',df)
#calculate precentage of aggregated functions
df2 = df.groupby(['Courses', 'Fees']).agg({'Fees': 'sum'})
print(df2)

# Percentage by lambda and DataFrame.apply() method.
df3 = df2.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:100 * x / float(x.sum()))
print(df3)
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: This is also super - thanks for answering!